# How do I parse an object column containing dates to convert in datetime format recognized by python

Tags: python-3.x

```
df3 = pd.concat([dataframe0, dataframe1])
df3.shape
Out[13]: (29807, 11)
df3['Created Date'].dtype

Out[22]: dtype('O')

df3['Created Date'] = df3['Created Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]') 

ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Tue Jun 25 2019 00:13:23 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)')



'Created Date' column contains date in (Fri Jun 28 2019 00:01:12 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)) format
```

Comment: Show us a few more rows please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that extra text: "(Pacific Daylight Time)" so I wrote a regex to remove it. The regex looks for everything up to any whitespace before an open paren/bracket.

From there you can use a function with `dt.datetime.strptime()` to convert your date string to a pandas datetime64. Please note that there is a call to `.strip()` in the date converter function. This is because I didn't see a way to remove the trailing whitespace within the regex.

```
import datetime as dt 
import pandas as pd

def date_converter(date_str):
  return dt.datetime.strptime(date_str.strip(),'%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z')

df = pd.DataFrame(['Tue Jun 25 2019 00:13:23 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)'],columns=['a'])
pattern = r'^(.*?)((?:(?!\s\().)*)$'
df['b'] = df['a'].str.replace(pattern,r'\1')
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(date_converter)

>>> print(df)
                                                   a                         b
0  Tue Jun 25 2019 00:13:23 GMT-0700 (Pacific Day... 2019-06-25 00:13:23-07:00

>>> df['b'].dtype
datetime64[ns, UTC-07:00]
```